# count++ and ++count, when to use which?

Tags: c#, increment

So i came across this little incrementing method

since highschool and univeristy I am used to this kind of method

```
char[] NewArray = new char[5] //I forgot how to declare an array

string temp;

console.writeline("Enter 5 letters)

for (i=0; i<5;i++)
{
   NewArray[i] = console.readline()
}
```

now based on this code

I declare an array of char with 5 "spaces", then I ouput a message to the console asking the user to enter 5 values

so i = 0, readline e.g. c

thus BEFORE the console.readline statment, i=0, then it continues through the for loop, then returns to the beginning of the loop, incrementing i = 1 BEFORE excecuting the console.readline again

**how does this differ to "++i", what will the "++i" do in the for loop?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`count++` is post increment where `++count` is pre increment. suppose you write `count++` means value increase after execute this statement. but in case `++count` value will increase while executing this line.

Answer (score 15):

++x is pre-increment and x++ is post-increment that is in the first x is incremented before being used and in the second x is incremented after being used.

if you write x++ or ++x they are same;.
if `x=5;`
`x++=6` and `++x=6`

but if you execute `x++ + x++`(5 +6) it will give you different result will be 11

but if you execute `x++ + ++x`(5 +7) it will give you different result will be 12

but if you execute `++x + ++x`(6 +7) it will give you different result will be 13

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't differ in the for loop.Because if your condition is true once for loop will execute ,then it perform your step. So this:

```
for(int=0; i<4; i++)
```

Equals to:

```
for(int=0; i<4; ++i)
```

You can think it's like the same as:

```
i++;
```

and;

```
 ++i;
```

Answer (score 1):

As additional information. This is how you can imagine the two different operators are implemented:

Prefix:

```
int operator++ () { 
    //let "this" be the int where you call the operator on
    this = this + 1;
    return this;
}
```

Postfix:

```
int operator++ (int) { //the dummy int here denotes postfix by convention
    //let "this" be the int where you call the operator on
    int tmp = this; //store a copy value of the integer (overhead with regards to prefix version)
    this = this + 1; //increment
    return tmp; //return the "pre-incremented" value
}
```